# How to REpublish Custom Task Forms (InfoPath) to SharePoint 2010 State Machine Workflows

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, infopath

I am new to SharePoint. Sorry if answer to my question is obvious.

1. I've create Custom Task Form in InfoPath and publish it (File/Publish/Network Location [Form Template Path and filename='MYPROJECT/Forms/ApprovalForm.xsn'; Form template name='ApprovalForm'], in the next window I've cleared Public URL according to the article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/195348/SharePoint-2010-State-Machine-Workflows-with-Custo).
2. After it I've added module Forms, and added ApprovalForm.xsn from the existing items.
3. My xml files:
   Elements.xml

   ```
   <Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
      <Workflow
          Name="Order New Server"
          Description="My SharePoint Workflow"
          Id="482cbc86-b717-4981-a49a-3cf4c89e9399"
          CodeBesideClass="Myproj.OrderNewServer.OrderNewServer"
          CodeBesideAssembly="$assemblyname$" 
          TaskListContentTypeId="0x01080100C9C9515DE4E24001905074F980F93160">
      <Categories/>
      <AssociationData><Data></Data></AssociationData>
      <MetaData>
         <AssociationCategories>List</AssociationCategories>      
         <Task2_FormURN>urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:infopath:ApprovalForm:-myXSD-2012-03-09T14-11-55</Task2_FormURN>
         <StatusPageUrl>_layouts/WrkStat.aspx</StatusPageUrl>
      </MetaData>
     </Workflow>
   </Elements>
   ```

Feature.Template.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <Feature xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" ReceiverAssembly="Microsoft.Office.Workflow.Feature, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" Receiverlass="Microsoft.Office.Workflow.Feature.WorkflowFeatureReceiver">
    <Properties>
      <Property Key="GloballyAvailable" Value="true" />
      <Property Key="RegisterForms" Value="Forms\*.xsn"/>
    </Properties>
   </Feature>
```

My form work fine, but when I make changes and republish it, it doesn't update (I see old form). 
What I tryed:

1. IISReset
2. Clear all cookies and cache in IE
3. Retract solution, restart VS2010, reboot computer.
4. Change assembly number, guid.

I have no ideas, what can I try for republish my form with changes.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

PS: sorry for my writing. English is not my native language.

PPS: when I save new Form to new location and add it to the project, it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found how can I republish changes. But it seems more like crutch than solution, but it works: After republishing InfoPath form, I delete file from project (DEL on ApprovalForm.xsn in Solution explorer) and after it add it again. (Add/Existing Item). And then redeploy! Hurray!