# SharePoint 2010 Custom InfoPath task form error: The specified form cannot be found

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, infopath

I am using custom InfoPath task form  in my project. 
All works fine, but I can't add new one. When I add it and click on task associated with it I get error: "The specified form cannot be found".
After it I tryed using first working task form, save it with another name, change it FormURN to new, add it to my Forms module, but it doesn't work too. When after it I saved it with the first used name and changed FormURN back it works fine again. I can't understand why it happens. May be I have to clear cache or something else? Yesterday I encountered with similar problem, for which I found [work-around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9636017/how-to-republish-custom-task-forms-infopath-to-sharepoint-2010-state-machine-w), but now I haven't any ideas.

When it doesn't work:

**Forms/Elements.xml:**

```
...
<File Path="Forms\ApprovalFormNew.xsn" Url="Forms/ApprovalFormNew.xsn" />
...
```

**Forms/SharePointProjectItem.spdata**

```
...
<ProjectItemFile Source="ApprovalFormNew.xsn" Target="Forms\" Type="ElementFile" />
...
```

**Workflow/Elements.xml**

```
...
<Task2_FormURN>urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:infopath:ApprovalFormNew:-myXSD-2012-03-09T14-11-55</Task2_FormURN>
...
```

When it works in shown above places there are ApprovalForm instead of ApprovalFormNew.

**Feature.Template.xml:**

```
<Property Key="RegisterForms" Value="Forms\*.xsn"/>
```

Is there a way to see more detail information about this error? There is no details about it in logs.

What I've tryed: IISReset, clear IE cache, reboot.

Any help is very appreciated.

PS: Sorry for my writing, English is not my native language.

PPS: Also I can't use default (not InfoPath view) for Tasks when I don't change default TaskType. Is it normal and I have to use either default view or InfoPath views, but not both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it, problem was not in caching. When I changed name of my form and republished it, I've missed to clear public URL in InfoPath Publishing Wizard. I've cleared it, and now it  works fine.